# Get the value from function array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameter-passing

I have this question in the assignment and would love if anybody can help:

write a program to store integers in an array of size 10, initialize your array in a function Get_value() where the user will input 10  integers to fill the array. The program then print a menu given below for the user and must be able to perform various function that the user chooses ..the user commands are :
D display all non zero value in the array
T Display the total
R display all numbers in reverse order
Q quit the program
in c++
I tried to write but I didn't get the exact answer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int get_value();
int display();
void total(void);
int main ()
 {
int get_value[10];  
int i;
char c=0;

for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
    printf("Enter The value of get_value[%d]\n",i);
    scanf("%d",get_value[i]);
}

printf(" D to display all non-zero values in the array \n choose T to display the  total \n choose R to display all the number in reverse order \n choose Q to quit the program \n");
scanf("%d",&c);

if(c == D){
        display();
}
else if(c== T){
    total();
}
   return 0;

   }
int display()
{
    int i,get_value[10];
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
        if(get_value[i]!=0)
            printf("%d",get_value[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
void total(void)
{
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
        sum+=i;
    }
        printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Your description is very vague. Also, this is very C-like. Your `total` function is basically `std::accumulate`. Your `display` function is basically `std::copy_if`.

Comment: ahh, you are reading in an integer and then comparing it to as far as I can tell something that should be a compiler error. Do you have 'D' and 'T' #defined somewhere?

Comment: @robbmj, Or just plain declared. `#define` isn't the right tool for that.

Comment: how can i send the value from the main to the definition and print it

Comment: @user3088939, Pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @robbmj i can write it as, if (c=='T')

Comment: how can i pass it if i dont hve value to put it in parameter

Comment: ya I know that works, I am just wondering about scanf

Comment: i replace it to integer value to be more easily  like (c==1) (c==2)..

Comment: @robbmj in the definition i cant get correct value  .. why ?

Comment: I just posted an answer have a look at that

Comment: @robbmj it doesn't work with character i dont know why ... can you show me now how can i write the  definition please ?

Comment: yes it is working with char .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

```
if (c == D)
```

should be:

```
if (c == 'D')
```

Similarly:

```
else if (c == T)
```

should be:

```
else if (c == 'T')
```

There are various other problems too, e.g. as already pointed out int he comments:

```
scanf("%d",&c);
```

is incorrect - it should be:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

although:

```
c = getchar();
```

is probably better.

Comment: does
char c=0;
scanf("%d",&c);

work? address of char and it looks for an int. I know chars are just ints interpreted a different way and all.

Comment: @robbmj Good catch. I would not expect that to work to read a single character from the input.

Comment: Thanks - there seem to be quite a few problems with the code - I've added the scanf problem to the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_value();
int display(int values[], int n);
void total(int values[], int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    n = 10;
    int values[n];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
            printf("Enter The value of get_value[%d]\n",i);
        values[i] = get_value();
    }

    printf(" D to display all non-zero values in the array \n choose T to display the  total \n choose R to display all the number in reverse order \n choose Q to quit the program\n");


    char c;
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    if(c == 'D') {
            display(values, n);
    }
    else if(c == 'T') {
            total(values, n);
    }
    else if (c == 'R') {

    }
    return 0;
}

int get_value()
{
        int usersChoice;
    scanf("%d", &usersChoice);
    return usersChoice;
}

int display(int values[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        if(values[i]!=0)
            printf("%d", values[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void total(int values[], int n)
{
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        sum+=values[i];
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

I think this will answer all your questions.

Comment: it working now .. but the output is wrong .. how can i send the value for the definition ?